# Post JSON data in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, express, multipartform-data

I am using React on the front-end & expressJs for server. I have some javascript `Object` data to send to the server. I `JSON.stringify` the data & then store it in `<textarea/>` within the form & I then I just post it.

I am using the modules 'body-parser' for general api calls & 'multer' for this multi-part form submission.

Front-end code:

```
  <div>
    <form action="/api/query" method="POST">
    {/* following textarea value looks like this:
    {"collection":"Contract","fieldSets":[{"field":"location","value":"London","andOr":""}],"responseType":"csv"} */}
      <textarea defaultValue={JSON.stringify({ collection, fieldSets, responseType: 'csv' })} />
      <Button type="submit">Download</Button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Back-end code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
const app = express();
app.set('port', 1111);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// for parsing multipart/form-data
app.use(upload.array());
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/query', (req, res) => {
   // here I keep getting reqbody as an empty {}
  console.log('reqbody is...', req.body);
```

However, I keep getting `{}` within `req.body` on the server.
To clarify, the `/api/query` does work as I am able to `fetch` data from the url & display on front-end. Its the form submission post which doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML form input fields should have a `name` attribute to be accepted, otherwise they are ignored in the form submission. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input](http://MDN%20Input)

The above work with the following change:

```
...
// added name attribute
<textarea name="reqData" defaultValue={JSON.stringify({ collection, fieldSets, responseType: 'csv' })} />
...
```

Answer (score -1):

JSON.stringify will just stringify the object. in your case looks like you are replacing the object. your syntax looks like

`JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, space)`

better save your data in one variable and just stringify it by passing as first param to this.

refer :
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_stringify.asp

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I think you are getting confused by the syntax (es2015), I am passing one object within json.stringify. I also tried your way, and I am getting the same empty {} at server. Best,

Comment: if you are passing the same was as shown in above code then, you are not passing the values for "collection & fieldSets". try passing the values like collection = someCollection & fieldSets = someSets. then it makes the object then only it can parse.

Comment: I highly recommend you try the above code style in your browser console. You will realise it works :) The above merely means: JSON.stringify({ collection : ...collection, fieldSets : ...fieldSets, responseType: 'csv' })